# Convert textBox to DateTime

Tags: c#

Hello everyone i am  getting a hard time with his code and is very wear for me because is working i one project and is not in the other one, i am using the same Visual Studio, same computer, here is the code:

```
DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(this.textBoxDate1.Text);
 DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(this.textBoxDate2.Text);
 this.reportJobsTableAdapter.Fill(this.KableTechDataSet.reportJobs, date1, date2);
 this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: What is not working exactly? You get any exception or error message? Can you please be more specific about your problem? What are these `.Text` values and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: try `DateTime.Parse`

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @Plutonix `Convert.ToDateTime` explicitly uses `DateTime.Parse` already. I think we should get the real problem to clarify the question instead of suggesting another same method.

Comment: @Plutonix What difference that makes?

Comment: Ack!  I did not read it closely enough.  Sorry.

Comment: here is the error i am getting: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: Can you confirm, that your error occurs on the first or second line of the code you posted? From here it looks like you forgot a `.Text` property somewhere. And therefor the compiler tries to convert a Textbox instead of a string.

Comment: Are you sure this is your code and not `Convert.ToDateTime(this.textBoxDate1)` ? I believe you missed `.Text` part.

Comment: You cannot convert a `TextBox` to `DateTime`! But you can convert a `string` to `DateTime` and `textBoxDate1.Text` yields a `string`.

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(this.textBoxDate1.Text);
            DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(this.textBoxDate2.Text);
            this.reportJobsTableAdapter.Fill(this.KableTechDataSet.reportJobs, date1, date2);

            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.Parse(string)` method, for sample:

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Parse(this.textBoxDate1.Text);
```

Or if you can use `TryParse` if you are not sure about eh format

```
DateTime date1;
if (DateTime.TryParse(this.textBoxDate1.Text, out date1))
{
   // conversion ok
   // use date1
}
else 
{
   // conversion fail..
}
```

Comment: That's not the case based on OP's comment.

Comment: it's working thanks so much, i still thinking why is working in one project but nor in the other one???

Comment: You were probably missing the `.Text` in one of the projects. That's what the Exception is telling you (if you read between the lines).